# Почему не отображаются фотографии в админке сайта?

Tags: django, django-admin

Не отображаются фотографии в админке сайта Django (вместо них квадратики с вопросом), но на самом сайте все показывает нормально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'category', 'pub_date', 'is_published', 'get_photo')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'title')
    search_fields = ('id', 'title', 'content')
    list_editable = ('is_published', 'category')
    list_filter = ('pub_date','is_published',)
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'content', 'category', 'pub_date', 'is_published','photo', 'get_photo')
    readonly_fields = ('id', 'get_photo', 'pub_date')


    def get_photo(self, obj):
        if obj.photo:
            return mark_safe(f'<img src="{obj.photo.url}" width="75px">')

    get_photo.short_description = 'Миниатюра'
```

Comment: покажите код. Как вы выводите изображения в админке.

Comment: я добавил код. Сразу не догадался вставить его

Comment: откройте изображение по приведенному урлу и сравните с тем, что должно быть (что работает на сайте). скорее всего не хватает медиа в путях.

Comment: Не заметил, что на сайте тоже пропали изображения. Буду решать проблему

Comment: проверьте настройки nginx, пути к медиа